# PHP: How do you avoid the use of extract() in a specific case

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, extract

I'm very new to PHP and have been reading everywhere that the use of the extract function is not recommended. I'm fetching data from a mysql table to populate a section of a website. Therefore I don't know how many rows the table could have.

So I'm using the extract function which gives me an array of arrays for each row. In order to create some variables that would facilitate the 'echoing' of each field I'm using this code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM example";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$gharray = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$arrayrows = array_keys($gharray);
foreach ($arrayrows as $arrayrow) {
   $i = $arrayrow;
};
foreach ($gharray[$i] as $ghimg) {
   extract ($gharray[$i], EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "img"."$i");
};
```

It gets the job done and creates variables such as:
`$img1_title, $img1_description, $img2_title`, etc. (This will be mentioned in a comment so these variables have an explanation when backtracking.

But I'm wondering if this is a correct use or if there's a simpler, cleaner solution to achieve the same results. Or if there's a set limit of rows (i.e six) would you do it differently?

We sanitize all the content posted to the database so there should be no trouble. (Plus the admin is the only one who can post info there). Anyway help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing with this code: `foreach ($arrayrows as $arrayrow) { $i = $arrayrow; };`? Are you trying to find the last value in `$arrayrow`?

Comment: can't see why tou dont just work with the arrays

Comment: Why are you using extract in the first place?  Why do the array elements have to become variable names?  I'm very confused as to why you'd need to do this.  Maybe you can post more code so we can understand your requirements better?

Comment: `extract` has its place, I guess the (justifiable) worry is that it can pollute the current scope with arbitrary, implicitly-defined variables - which makes it very hard for someone to reason about the code you have written. Remember that code is "written once and read often". It's hard to tell what your intention is from the example code you provided, but I'd suggest a nested loop might be appropriate, and more readable.

Comment: Ok, thanks four your input on this. 
@Darragh To your 1st comment: As the `fetch_all` function gives me an array with a nested array for each row of the table. That first `foreach` is letting me extract each of those "row-arrays" separately and asigning a custom `$i` variable for each field. 

@Dagon, @raduation You mean like `$array[]["fieldname"]`? I'll have to put each field of the array on several places, so I figured out it would be easier to simply put `echo $variablename` whenever I want to place anything, as it would also improve readability. (Comparing to `$array[]["fieldname"]`)

Comment: @Darragh It would take ages to declare each variable independently and it would require for me to know the amount of rows on said table. If there where 6 rows with 3 fields for each one it would mean declaring 18 variables. 

Or maybe I'm overdoing this, but I can't think of a better way, to me this is what I found to be more consistent with the "written once and read often" approach. 

This is to be used on a separate .php file which would be included into the files where the variables would be echoed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `list ()` but you'll need an enumerated array. Check PHP Documentation:

```
$row = [];
$row[0] = 123;
$row[1] = 'data';
 list($id, $data) = $row;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php

Basically `list($id, $data) = $row;` does:

```
$id = $row[0];
$data = $row[1];
```

Which is way shorter with more variables.

Comment: Hey @MinusFour this seems great although I'm beginning to understand what people here mean about working only with the arrays. However I don't yet fully understand how are the values of the list assigned from an array nested within an array, as this is my case.

Comment: You still need to iterate the result set which has arrays with the actual data. But instead of extracting everything into their separate variable, you choose exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks I get it now! Extremely useful, at least for presentation cases. It's a little more work but I'm all for learning to avoid bad practices.

I don't still fully understand how to make it dynamic, as I don't know how many rows will the table be and I also need to take three column fields for each row...

Comment: I have this now:
`$result = mysqli_query($link,$query);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$hgarray = mysqli_fetch_all($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
list($ghimg1,$ghimg2, $ghimg3, $ghimg4, $ghimg5, $ghimg6) = $hgarray;
list ($ghimg1_id, $ghimg1_title, $ghimg1_image, $ghimg1_descrip) = $ghimg1; 
list ($ghimg2_id, $ghimg2_title, $ghimg2_image, $ghimg2_descrip) = $ghimg2;`.... etc.
The problem is again that I don't know how many rows are there gonna be, right now it has only two, so I get errors of undefined variables for `$ghimg3, $ghimg4` and related as they don't yet even exist.

Comment: Well that doesn't make much sense to me. Why do you want to dump the entire result set? You are better off iterating the result set. Like `foreach($gharray as $row) { list($ghimg_id, $ghimg_time, $ghimg_image, $ghimg_descript) = $row; //Now you work with those variables inside this scope }`

Comment: I get what you mean, but what I don't know is by using such code; wouldn't the `$ghimg_id` be the same for each id.  How would I know which of the IDs I'm using when I put `echo $ghimg_id`. 
I'm trying to put all of this in a separate file to be included in the files where such variables are to be included. So those 'markup' files are more readable.

Answer (score 0):

**Counting variables:**

To count variables (which seems to be the intention of your first loop?), you can use:

```
    $number_of_rows_in_your_array = count($arrayrows);
```

**Cleaner solution:**

You weren't very specific on HOW you want to populate the site. Assuming that you want to populate a simply table with identical row structures, then you don't need x variables. Insteady, You could replace both of your loops with something like this:

```
    echo '
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Header row
        </td>
      </tr>';
      for($x=0;$x=count($arrayrows);$x++){
        echo '
        <tr>
          <td>
             '.$arrayrows[$x].'
          </td>
        </tr>';
      }
    echo '
    </table>';
```

Here, I'm using the array and I'm displaying the $ith element with each iteration. Thus, there's no need for x variables.

Comment: I'm trying to separate the operational php from the markup as much as possible, therefore I would put the code posted in a separate file and include it in the markup files where the variables need to be echoed. NO TABLES in the markup.

The intention of the first `foreach` loop is not to count, but to be able to call each row separately. 

I  know I could probably echo using `echo $gharray[0]["title"]` but it would be difficult to read as opposed to `echo $img1_title`